# Changing the column labels color based on width of chart

Tags: bar-chart, anychart

I have created a bar chart that has the values of each of the columns at the end of each bar. The color of the bars is the same as the text of the values. The problem is that based on the width of the container/browser by default the values move inside the bar. But then you can't read the text as the bar and text are the same. I would prefer to have the values outside the bar but when they have to move inside the bar due to space is there a way to change the font color to white so that it is readable? Here is an example of the chart.

https://playground.anychart.com/DAlu15WO/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no possibility to detect if the label was moved inside the bar or not. But you can enable label background to increase its readability like in [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/uX9u1TVT).
Pay attention to lines 96-97.
All available background settings you can find in [the list](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.ui.Background).

Comment: I have a follow up question. When I set the position to inside the labels are moved inside the bar but the are not centered in the bar. Why is that? See line 96. It is currently commented out. Thanks for your previous response.
https://playground.anychart.com/S996pCcF/1

Comment: Because the default label anchor is "left-bottom". You should apply the "center" anchor. Check the modified sample (line 97) - https://playground.anychart.com/RqEEmcGN